# How can download single file by multithreading concept

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsurlsession

I have a large single file, but I want to download this file with 2 concurrent threads, where both threads will download chunk by chunk and the same will be stored in local files by concatenation.

I am not sure whether or not it is possible in iOS. If yes, please let me know how it can be achieved. Code is not necessary. Sharing the concept would do just fine, but technical terms should be in context of iOS. As we know, NSURLSession is the supported API for iOS.

Comment: why do you want to download same file two times ?

Comment: You can say this is kinda of requirement..... I am looking whether it is possible or not..

Comment: It is, but it's not going to be any faster if that is your hope

Comment: yeah this is possible! you can generate two separate request simultaneously !

Comment: @Lion - are you seen this `will be stored in local files by concatenation`

Comment: If I will generate 2 separate request how 2 threads will understand to what range they have to download the bytes. Creating 2 separate thread will start downloading from beginning  for both of them. How they communicate for chunk download from specific range? In resulting they need to store chunk in a same local file.

Comment: okay. I have misunderstood your need! Please ignore my comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can download a single file in multiple parts with range requests. For that you have to set the range header in your requests, e. g.: `Range: bytes=200-1000` will load only bytes 200 to 1000 of the file, But you should check if your server will support that.

You can set (range) headers in `NSMutableRequest` with `addValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField:)` or `addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`, resp. If you send your requests with `NSURLSession` they will be executed in parallel automatically.

Comment: More specific.... and giving the result also ... :)
Do you have idea why this is important.... would it be good to work with 2 separate threads instead of one...???

Comment: May be I am right... If one thread is taking 10 minutes to download the task but if 2 threads taking 5-5 minutes to download the task we can achieve whole downloading in only 5 minutes of time... Thanks macmoonshine...

Comment: `NSURLSession` will execute the request in a background. You should not start separate threads. This should not be necessary.

Comment: I think that the total download time will not be halved, because it's limited to the total bandwidth.